# joining same table on different relations

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables. Users, Objects and Items. Users can have many Objects and objects can have many items. Also, Users can have many Items. And I'm doing report for these tables.

My result should look like:

```
+------------+----------------+-----------------+
| username   | Object         | Item            |
+------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  1001      | Object_name1   | Item_name1      |
|  1001      | NULL           | Item_name2      |
|  1001      | NULL           | Item_name3      |
|  1001      | NULL           | Item_name4      |
|  1001      | NULL           | Item_name5      |
|  1002      | NULL           | Item_name6      |
+------------+----------------+-----------------+
and so on..
```

The best what i get with my current query:

```
SELECT u.username, o.name as object, i.name as item, i1.name as item_1
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN object_user as ou on ou.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN objects as o on o.id = ou.object_id
LEFT JOIN object_items as oi on oi.object_id = o.id
LEFT JOIN items as i on i.id = oi.item_id
LEFT JOIN item_user as iu on iu.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN items as i1 on i1 = iu.item_id
```

```
+------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| username   | Object         | Item            | Item_1          |
+------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  1001      | Object_name1   | Item_name1      | Item_name2      |
|  1001      | Object_name1   | Item_name1      | Item_name3      |
|  1001      | Object_name1   | Item_name1      | Item_name4      |
|  1001      | Object_name1   | Item_name1      | Item_name5      |
|  1002      | NULL           | NULL            | Item_name6      |
+------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

my schema:
[image]
and, as you can see, it's incorrect. Any advice how to solve it?

Comment: We need the table data as well, for that result.

Comment: I added DB schema

Answer (score 0):

You could useing two time the join for item one for objects related  items and one for users realated  items

```
SELECT u.username, o.name as object, oi.name as oi_item_name, ui.name as ui_item_name
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN objects o on o.id = u.object_id 
LEFT JOIN items  oi on o.item_id  = oi.id
LEFT JOIN items ui on u.item_id  = ui.id
```